# Resolving duplicate cookie error log messages in Apache 2.4

Tags: apache-2.4, logging, cookies

Running Apache 2.4.7, our error logs are cluttered with messages like:

```
 [core:error] ... AH00011: ap_cookie: client submitted cookie 'PHPSESSID' more than once: ...
```

We haven't been able to determine any specific failure in behavior due to this, but also have not had success duplicating it.

Is this something we could be causing with our application configuration? If so, is there a preventative measure we could be taking to eliminate it?

Or, is it not worrisome, and if so, how would we prevent these messages from cluttering the log? (I am guessing it *is* worrisome, but just in case...)

Comment: Have seen this sort of thing with JESSIONIDs when clients access multiple underlying applications via a common "portal" that manages the cookies. You could also use a browser developer tools to trace all the HTTP requests to see if its particular requests that cause the additional cookie to be set. Essentially you need to try to find out where and when the PHPSESSID cookies are being set.

Comment: Interesting -- we do have two separate PHP applications deployed that work together, so perhaps we are experiencing the same thing. I will go down that path and see what i can find.